# How to fix vulnerabilities from AWS ECR Image Scans

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, security, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to fix some Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures from my docker images hosted at AWS ECR.

I have a Debian Bullseye that is basically a copy from the official python 3.11 bullseye slim image.

When I run a scan in it, ECR shows the CVE-2019-8457 - SQLite3 from 3.6.0 to and including 3.27.2 is vulnerable to heap out-of-bound read in the rtreenode() function when handling invalid rtree tables.

I tried to remove both sqlite3 and db5.3 from the image, but the [warning persists](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2019-8457).

```
RUN apt-get purge --auto-remove sqlite3 -y
RUN apt-get purge --auto-remove libsqlite3-dev -y
RUN apt-get purge --auto-remove db5.3-util -y
```

So my final question is: The scan is performed in the base image? Is there a way to fix this CVEs?

Comment: Why cant you upgrade the base image or update the dependencies?